# Copy.deepcopy vs creating new instances in magic methods

Tags: python, magic-methods

When over-riding python **add**, **mul** etc magic methods, it seems to be normal to create a new instance of the class and then return that. For example:

```
class test_class_simple:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __add__(self, other):
        return test_class(self.x + other.x)
```

However, another option is to have the **add** method copy the existing instance and then just change its value:

```
import copy
def __add__(self, other):
    new = copy.deepcopy(self)
    new.x = self.x + other.x
    return new
```

When working with complex classes with lots of variables, it seems easier and probably also safer to deepcopy them (as per example 2) and then to change the particular attribute that the magic method affects. However I don't see many examples of people doing this, and so I'm wondering if there's some drawback to it further down the line that I'm unaware of. Is there any harm to this approach?

Thanks!

Comment: You see that as easier? Doesn't seem that way to me.

Comment: @user2357112
I guess it's situation-dependent, but if you have a class that takes a lot of arguments to instantiate, it requires less code.

Comment: What kind of situations are you running into where a class takes a lot of arguments, *and* it supports `__add__`, *and* you don't need to end up adjusting just as much state if you make a copy as if you'd just used the constructor? Also, `deepcopy` is slow and doesn't handle cyclical references anywhere near as well as it's supposed to. [Here's an example of it getting cyclical references wrong](https://ideone.com/1RxgnM), and [here's an example of it being really slow](https://ideone.com/yLWxfh).

Comment: @user2357112
Thanks for the links there - I didn't realise the shortcomings of deepcopy. Rest assured that yes, this is an actual situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with your first way of overriding `__add__`. A couple reasons why:

- `copy.deepcopy()` is written in Python, not C, so you probably aren't going to get any performance gains from doing this
- Using `copy.deepcopy()` isn't as clear as just instantiating a new object, because the object returned by the `__add__` doesn't have any direct relationship with the current object
- If the object you're instantiating has some kind of self-referential cycle, `copy.deepcopy()` might get stuck, as it uses recursion to do the deep copy.

Comment: `copy.deepcopy` is *supposed* to handle reference cycles, but it doesn't do a very reliable job of it.

Comment: Right, and there's a lot of overhead in keeping track of reference cycles, so I think that's another reason for instantiating a new object!

Comment: @PeterWang
Thanks Peter, that makes sense to me and it seems like the right route to go.